# My memory leak in C++ program

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, new-operator, delete-operator

I'm faced a new problem something with memory allocation and leak here  is my error log:

```
Dr. Memory version 1.4.6 build 2 built on Mar  7 2012 10:14:04
Application cmdline: ""D:\c++\Begin\Lab3-5_OOP\Debug\Lab3-5_OOP.exe""
Recorded 62 suppression(s) from default C:\Program Files (x86)\Dr. Memory/bin/suppress-default.txt

Error #1: UNINITIALIZED READ: reading register eax
# 0 _fu89___ZSt4cout               [D:\c++\Begin\Lab3-5_OOP\Debug/../Controller.cpp:156]
# 1 main                           [D:\c++\Begin\Lab3-5_OOP\Debug/../M.cpp:25]
Note: @0:00:00.924 in thread 4584
Note: instruction: test   %eax %eax

Error #2: LEAK 12 direct bytes 0x00531420-0x0053142c + 1024 indirect bytes
# 0 libstdc++-6.dll!Znwj           
# 1 constr()               [D:\c++\Begin\Lab3-5_OOP\Debug/../ListStruc.cpp:24]
# 2 main                   [D:\c++\Begin\Lab3-5_OOP\Debug/../M.cpp:18]

Error #3: LEAK 12 direct bytes 0x009bec48-0x009bec54 + 1024 indirect bytes
# 0 libstdc++-6.dll!Znwj  +0x23     (0x6fcbb523 <libstdc++-6.dll+0x7b523>)
# 1 constr()               [D:\c++\Begin\Lab3-5_OOP\Debug/../ListStruc.cpp:24]
# 2 main                   [D:\c++\Begin\Lab3-5_OOP\Debug/../M.cpp:20]

DUPLICATE ERROR COUNTS:

SUPPRESSIONS USED:

ERRORS FOUND:
      0 unique,     0 total unaddressable access(es)
      1 unique,     1 total uninitialized access(es)
      0 unique,     0 total invalid heap argument(s)
      0 unique,     0 total warning(s)
      2 unique,     2 total,   2072 byte(s) of leak(s)
      0 unique,     0 total,      0 byte(s) of possible leak(s)
ERRORS IGNORED:
     78 still-reachable allocation(s)
         (re-run with "-show_reachable" for details)
Details: C:\Users\Warzaru\AppData\Roaming/Dr. Memory/DrMemory-Lab3-5_OOP.exe.10024.000/results.txt
```

Struct:

```
const int days=31;
const int exp=6;

struct Arr{
    int days;
    int exp;
    int **M;
};
typedef Arr* Array;
```

Constructor:

```
void constr(Array &loc){
    //Construct of 31*6 Matrix, were 31 nr. of days and 6 specific types:
    //0-HouseKeeping, 1-Food, 2-Transport, 3-Clothing, 4-TelNet, 5-others
    loc=new Arr;
    loc->days = days;
    loc->exp = exp;
    loc->M = new int*[loc->days];
    for(int i=0; i<loc->days;i++ ){
       loc->M[i] = new int[loc->exp];
       for (int j = 0; j < loc->exp; j++){
           loc->M[i][j] = 0;
       }
    }
}
```

The program  errors me only for some  function of ti for example function:

```
void maxDay(Array &M){
    //Output the day with highest value
    cout<<"test";
    int hD = 0;
    int s1 = 0;
    int s2 = 0;
    cout<<"test";
    for(int i = 0; i<30;i++){
        s1=0;
        for (int j=0; i<5; j++){
            s1 = s1 + M->M[i][j];
            if(s2 <= s1){
                s2 = s1;
                hD = i;
                cout<<"test";
            }
        }
    }

}
```

So short, I have a structure `Arr` ( Matrix of 31*6) were I store ints (different types of expenses) but when I use some of my functions I get Segmentation fault. I have no experience with this kind of errors, so any advices are useful.

EDIT:

```
void destruc(Array &loc){
    for(int i=0; i<loc->days;i++ ){
       delete[] loc->M[i];
       for (int j = 0; j < loc->exp; j++){
           delete[] loc->M[i][j];
   }
}
}
```

Comment: I see `new` but not `delete`.

Comment: I suggest you replace `int **M` with `std::vector< std::vector<int> >`. Actually, there are better approaches, but this would have the least impact on your existing solution.

Comment: the thing  is I have to use my own structure :|

Comment: @BogdanMaier: If this is homework, you need to tag it as homework, otherwise you will get proper/suitable answers that you can't use because of the restrictions imposed by your homework guidelines.

Comment: ok, thank you i`ll keep in mind for the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The destructor in seems to be strange

```
void destruc(Array &loc){
    for(int i=0; i<loc->days;i++ ){
       delete[] loc->M[i]; <-------------- deleting array of pointers to array
       for (int j = 0; j < loc->exp; j++){
           delete[] loc->M[i][j]; <------- deleting pointer to array that
                                           is already deallocated
   }
}
```

Destructor should look the following way (in accordance to constructor):

```
void destruc(Array &loc){
    for(int i=0; i<loc->days;i++ ){
       delete[] loc->M[i];
    }
    delete[] M;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the rule "Deallocate every block of memory that you have allocated dynamically"

Deallocate using `delete` the memory you have allocated using `new`

This may throw some light for you http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/

If you allocated an array using `new[]` then delete it using `delete[]`

In this case i would suggest you to write a constructor and destructor for the `struct Arr` instead of writing normal functions.

Comment: is it  correct like this? i edited the psot and added deconstrctor.

Comment: You are mixing `delete[]` and `delete` with `new` and `new[]`

Answer (score 1):

```
// I hope you intended to write j<5
for (int j=0; i<5; j++){  //infinite Loop... as j is still 0
```

So what happens with the statement `i<5` in your program is, your inner for loop becomes an indefinite loop and tries to access unallocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
1    void destruc(Array &loc) {
2        for(int i=0; i<loc->days;i++ ) {
3            delete[] loc->M[i];
4            for (int j = 0; j < loc->exp; j++) {
5                delete[] loc->M[i][j];
6            }
7        }
8    }
```

i see you're delete[]'ing loc->M[i] (line 3) and yet you still references it's contents at line 5.

I suggest this is a bug as you've handed the memory back to the heap and any other part of your application can now re-use it. So by the time your application gets to line 5 it may not have the contents you expect.

I'd suggest rewriting it as...

```
1    void destruc(Array &loc) {
2        for(int i=0; i<loc->days;i++ ) {
3            for (int j = 0; j < loc->exp; j++) {
4                delete[] loc->M[i][j];
5            }
6            delete[] loc->M[i];
7        }
8    }
```